# WsShell.Run don't accept variable (e.g. T1) as Argument or Parameter

Tags: c#

Below two c# procedures `Test1` & `Test2` one is working and one is not working, if anyone know why, please help.

```
// Not Working X    
    protected void Test1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string T1;
        T1 = "winword.exe c:/sql_pt_c/mydocx.docx";
        string javaScript =
            "<script language=JavaScript>\n" +
            "WshShell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');\n" +
            "WshShell.Run(T1, 1, true);\n" +
            "</script>";
        RegisterStartupScript("", javaScript);
    }


// Working v/
    protected void Test1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string javaScript =
            "<script language=JavaScript>\n" +
            "WshShell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');\n" +
            "WshShell.Run('winword.exe c:/sql_pt_c/mydocx.docx', 1, true);\n" +
            "</script>";
        RegisterStartupScript("", javaScript);
    }
```

Comment: `T1` is a variable in the code behind (I assume this is ASP.NET) which runs on the server, whereas the code you're registering as a startup script will be running in the browser of the users machine. They're running at two different times and in two different contexts. And since option 2 works, why not just use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to concatenate `T1`

```
string T1 = "winword.exe c:/sql_pt_c/mydocx.docx";
string javaScript =
        "<script language=JavaScript>\n" +
        "WshShell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');\n" +
        "WshShell.Run('"+T1+"', 1, true);\n" +
        "</script>";
```

Right now, you included the literal string "T1" and not the value of the variable

Comment: I think you want a couple of `'`s in there also - otherwise it becomes `WshShell.Run(winword.exe c:/sql...)` which won't parse as javascript correctly.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I got you! Thanks.

Comment: Hi codingbiz, u r right, must change to T1 = "'winword.exe c:/sql_pt_c/mydocx.docx'"

Comment: Hi codingbiz, enter too fast, forget to say thank you to you. Thanks a lot............... .Do you know you just save someone a lot of time and effort. Good job!

Comment: I know this could have been an oversight on your part, just a simple mistake, so no problem. Now that your problem is solved, you can either delete this question or mark this answer as the right answer that solved your problem. If the latter, there is a tick mark beside the answer to click on. You can also upvote if you have up to 15 reputation - these are ways to say thank you on StackOverflow. :D